# Modal qTip - hide when ... mouseleave?

Tags: jquery, qtip

im using the modal window qTip. Everything works fin, but i was wondering if it is posible to hide the modal window on either when onMouseout or mouseleave... and how?

this is my current setting:

```
hide: {
   when: {
      event: 'unfocus'
   }
},
```

Of course the unfocus only works when clicking outside. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this too:

```
hide: {when: {event:'mouseout unfocus'}, fixed: true, delay: 500}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hide: {
  when: {
    event: 'mouseout'
  }
}
```