# jquery qTip not hide tooltip when unfocus use tab key

Tags: qtip

I apply qtip on my form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
...
show: 'focus',
hide: 'unfocus'
</script>

<input type="text" name="username" size="30" alt="Tài khoản không được để trống" /> <br />
<input type="text" name="password" size="30" alt="Mật khẩu của bạn" /> <br />
```

But, it's only work well when i click for each input, when i press key Tab on keyboard it's show all tooltip not hide when mouse unfocus, how to fix it

Comment: you got a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

**Special events**

qTip2 implements some custom hide and show events for you so you don't have to code the manually. At the moment there's only one: unfocus. This event allows you to hide the tooltip when anything other then the tooltip is clicked.

```
$('.selector').qtip({
    content: {
        text: 'I\'ll hide when you click anywhere else on the document'
    },
    hide: {
        event: 'unfocus'
    }
});
```

Note: This is a qTip only event, it will not work with any normal jQuery bind/live/delegate calls.

That being said, I don't believe that "unfocus" is the only one, because I have used click and it works.

[See this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859321/), it seems to have fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

Tried this?

```
$('.selector').qtip({
    content: {
        text: 'I\'ll hide when you click anywhere else on the document',
    },
    hide: {
        event: 'unfocus'//event: 'click mouseleave'
    }
});
```

Comment: It worked then. I didn't intend to follow a jq plugin for four years anyway. Peace ;)